# Is there an API to track DocuSign sent envelops status?

Tags: docusignapi

My task is to build a dashboard for a company to track the status of their sent DocuSign agreements to the clients(such as are they signed or not)and link to the document via the dashboard. I referred to their API docs and did not found a clear solution. As it is, I need to know if there is an API to track my requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do that with the eSignature API.
If you know the envelopeID and you are the sender (you = authenticated use calling the API) you can check the status of an envelope (here is a how-to guide with code examples in 8 languages showing how to do this - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/get-envelope-information/)

However, this approach is called "polling" since you are calling the API and may need to do that frequently to update your status.
The other, better approach, is using a webhook that let you know about any change in status. It's called DocuSign Connect.

Information about using DocuSign Connect webhook can be found here - https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/connect/